# How do I write a Regular Expression to match any three digits except 2 numbers?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a numeric column in DataTable and I want to filter & select rows by LINQ using regular expression
I need to select all rows that field's value has any 15 length digits except that digits between index 3 and 5 not equal 351 and 308 ( index start by 0 )
for example the number `157000258746589` is valid and `865351000254789` is invalid because the number has a `351` from the fourth number to sixth number

I'm using a pattern `/^[0-9]{3}(351|308)[0-9]{9}$/` and need to the opposite it

Note: I can't using `Not` operator to reverse it because I follow a way by looping a list of strings contains expressions and use it to filter data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this expression might work, not sure though:

```
^(?!(^[0-9]{3}(?:351|308)[0-9]{9}$))\d{15}$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/N0ONNJ/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/N0ONNJ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]